# How to inherit a Cocoa class in a script

Tags: applescript

I'm new in Apple script but have several years of experience in Objective-C for iOS. I like an ability to use Cocoa classes in AppleScript bundle. But I don't understand how I can really subclass a Cocoa class. For example I write in my AppleScript bundle "testLib":

```
script Car
property parent : class "NSObject"

on workWithCar()
    log me's retainCount() as integer

end workWithCar

end script
```

But when I try to use it in AppleScript I get an error:

```
set carObj to Car of script "testLib"
carObj's workWithCar() -- script Car doesn't understand retainCount message (sorry I have localized text and I don't understand how it looks like in English)
```

It means that my Car isn't a real NSObject subclass. But If I create Cocoa Apple Script Application in Xcode

```
script AppDelegate
property parent : class "NSObject"

on applicationWillFinishLaunching_(aNotification)
    log me's retainCount() as integer -- returns 1
end applicationWillFinishLaunching_

end AppDelegate
```

I will see 1. There I can access all NSObject's methods, I think Apple does some magic transformation when it unarchives objects from xib. Can I get the same effect in code in my AppleScript bundle?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you are trying to make a simple script library without terminology.

( correct me if I am wrong)

Here is an example of a simple script Library:

```
on transform(sourceText, caseIndicator)
    set validCaseType to {"upper case", "lower case", "word case"}
    if caseIndicator is in validCaseType then
        -- create a Cocoa string from the passed text
        set the sourceString to current application's NSString's stringWithString:sourceText
        -- apply the indicated transformation to the Cocoa string
        if the caseIndicator is "upper case" then
            set the adjustedString to sourceString's uppercaseString()
        else if the caseIndicator is "lower case" then
            set the adjustedString to sourceString's lowercaseString()
        else if the caseIndicator is "word case" then
            set the adjustedString to sourceString's capitalizedString()
        end if
        -- convert from Cocoa string to AppleScript text
        return (adjustedString as text)

    else
        set errStr to caseIndicator & " is not valid case indicator" as text
        error errStr

    end if

end transform
```

Save this as a script bundle. And in one of the script Library folders.

I used the  Users one.  `~/Library/Script Libraries/`. If it does not exist just create it.

Your apps can have their own Script Libraries

Then open the Script's Bundle Contents drawer and check the:

**Applescript/Objective - C Library**  check box

[image: bundle drawer]

Save the file once more to set the changes.

Now in a normal Applescript you can run.

```
tell script "test"
    set the adjustedText to transform("the cat", "upper case")

end tell
```

This returns -> "THE CAT"

---

Knowing this means to use your code.

The script Library Bundle would be named "test" and the code:

```
--  Not needed here --> property parent : class "NSObject"


on workWithCar()
    log me's retainCount() as integer

end workWithCar
```

The Normal Applescript would be:

```
tell script "test"
    set the theCar to workWithCar()
 end tell
```

returns ->  `*1*`

Comment: Yes, I want to create a script library. Your answer showed me that a script library is represented as NSObject subclass. I didn't know it before, thanks. But what about another classes? Can I subclass NSWindowController or any other Cocoa classes and override its methods for example?

Comment: To be honest. I am not sure. To what end would you want to do this

Comment: I just want to work with UI in my Script Library. I want to create a window and put a webView on it, but webview can be created only on main thread. And I decided that I can do it in windowDidLoad of NSWindowController. I can create NSWindow and show it but without subclassing NSWindowController I can't get full control of the window.